# Ajax contact form not working in website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm just a beginner and trying to implement ajax contact form with php mailing script. But when I click on Submit nothing happens and nothing appears.

Below is my codes.

**HTML**

```
<form id="contactform" class="contact-form text-center" role="form">
    <!-- IF MAIL SENT SUCCESSFULLY -->
    <h6 class="success">
        <span class="olored-text icon_check"></span> Your message has been sent successfully.</h6>

    <!-- IF MAIL SENDING UNSUCCESSFULL -->
    <h6 class="error">
        <span class="colored-text icon_error-circle_alt"></span> E-mail must be valid.</h6>

    <input id="cf-name" type="text" name="cf-name" placeholder="Your Name">
    <input id="cf-email" type="email" name="cf-email" placeholder="Your Email">
    <input id="cf-address" type="text" rows="7" name="cf-address" placeholder="Your Home Address">
    <input id="cf-phone" type="text" rows="7" name="cf-phone" placeholder="Your Phone Number">
    <input type="submit" class="button alt" value="Submit" id="submit" name="submit" data-style="expand-left"/>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
// Function for email address validation
function isValidEmail(emailAddress) {

    var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);

    return pattern.test(emailAddress);

}
/* =================================
 CONTACT FORM
 =================================== */
$("#contactform").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $("#cf-name").val();
    var email = $("#cf-email").val();
    var address = $("#cf-address").val();
    var message = $("#cf-phone").val();
    var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&address=' + address + '&phone=' + message;

    function isValidEmail(emailAddress) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
        return pattern.test(emailAddress);
    }
    if (isValidEmail(email) && (message.length > 1) && (address.length > 1) && (name.length > 1)) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sendmail.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function () {
                $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
                $('.error').fadeOut(500);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $('.error').fadeIn(1000);
        $('.success').fadeOut(500);
    }
    return false;
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
// Get values from jquery
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$to = "name@email.com";
$subject = "New Email Subscriber";
$message = " Name: " . $name . "\r\n\r\n Email: " . $email . "\r\n\r\n Address: " . $address . "\r\n\r\n Phone: " . $phone;


$from = "ContactForm";
$headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; 

if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "invalid";
}
```

Can someone please fix this code? I don't what's wrong with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you linking your JS to your HTML?

Comment: I have used `<!-- jQuery Custom
  ================================================== -->
  <script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: and where in your HTML is that located?

Comment: It's located at the and of the all codes, I mean before closing the </body> tag.

Comment: good, it should be there. Do me a favor, after `success: function(){..}` add `,error: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { alert(textStatus); }` Let me know what you get.

Comment: Also, why are you suppressing errors on the `@mail()` function on PHP. remove the `@` . The mail function will return true or false, which you need for your conditional.

Comment: I don't understand this, could you please do this and post the code here?

Thank you

Comment: I cannot. Not until I have a stable answer. Look at this SO answer. Look at their JS `$.ajax` call, inside you can see the `error: function()` you need to add that to your code to catch errors. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918248/ajax-success-and-error-function-failure

Comment: I did how you said, and when I click on submit it appears a dialogue box called "error"

here is the screenshot > http://prntscr.com/elaaqu

Comment: ok alert the last parameter too, like this: `,error: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { alert(jqXHR); }` What do you see then?

Comment: It's showing "Not Found".

See this > http://prntscr.com/elaq5u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may have nothing to do with Ajax but the php native mail function; I recommend use something like phpMailer since they are much more reliable than native function.

Comment: Where can I find phpMailer ?