# Parse json from php in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$.ajax({
                                url: '{{ route('frontend.validation') }}?sex=' + $(".sex").val() + '&date=' + $(".date").val() + '&hour=' + $(".hour").val()+ '&track=' + $(".track").val(),
                                type: 'get',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                headers: {
                                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                                },
                                cache: false,
                                success: function (response) {
                                    $.each(response, function (key, value) {

                                        console.log(response);
                                    })
                                }
                            });
```

In result I have:

> {"status":"ok","message":"Twoja rezerwacja zosta\u0142a zrealizowana"}

in console I have:

> [Log] {status: "ok", message: "Twoja rezerwacja została zrealizowana"}
>   (projekt1.test, line 284) [Log] {status: "ok", message: "Twoja
>   rezerwacja została zrealizowana"} (projekt1.test, line 284)

I need check my status.
If it's "ok" - then message I want show in alert box.

When status = "error" them I want show alert with "Sorry, we have error with yours reservation".

How can I make it?

Comment: The ajax request has the option of `dataType: 'json'` on it, so the response is already going to be parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u have already json object so you don't need to parse. Remove each method ,it uses keys count so you get alert two times .

```js
success: function (response) {
   if(response.status==="ok"){
      alert("ok")   
    }
    else if(response.status==="error"){
      alert("error")
    }
 }
```

Comment: because you did put in each method. and your response have two keys. remove each method just take inside them. I edited in answer success method check it

Answer (score -1):

try this

```html
$.ajax({
        url: '{{ route('frontend.validation') }}?sex=' + $(".sex").val() + '&date=' + $(".date").val() + '&hour=' + $(".hour").val()+ '&track=' + $(".track").val(),
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            $.each(response, function (key, value) {

                
                var obj = JSON.parse( response );

                console.log(obj['status'])

            })
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

From [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

> The JSON.parse() takes the string text input and returns the object corresponding to the given JSON text.

Use `JSON.parse(response)` and then read the index "status" of the object.

Answer (score -1):

The question is already answered [HERE LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918248/ajax-success-and-error-function-failure)

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(response){  
        $.each(response, function (key, value) {
            if(response.status==="ok"){
                alert("Twoja rezerwacja została zrealizowana");   
            }
            else if(response.status==="error"){
                alert("Sorry, we have error with yours reservation");
            }
        })
    },
    error: function(response) { 
        alert("Sorry, we have error with yours reservation"); 
    }
});
return False;
....
```